# Unblock only specific attachment in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter, attachments, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm searching for a possibility to unblock a specific attachment in Outlook which was blocked by its file extension (Level1).

E.g. Outlook blocks `.exe` files. I don't want to unblock `.exe` files in general but in some specific cases it would be nice to override the block and say

> Yes I'm sure and I know what I'm doing

#### Why do I want this?

When receiving e.g. `.doc` files which can contain potentially unsafe VBA it would be nice to have an extra warning or extra step to unblock these files. But potentially safe files like `.pdf` or `.jpg` would open directly.

Any ideas how to *warn* from potentially unsafe files but not to block them in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Level2Remove/Level2Add registry values were for. But for some reason it doesn't work in Outlook 2016.

Comment: Hm this is what I immediately tried after I saw that there is a `Level1Add`. So sadly there is no information on the net why this isn't working anymore. So thanks for confirming this anyway.

Comment: Leve 2 is safe attachment, but forces to save to disk. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/829982 KB could be out of date, but support is listed up to Outlook 2010 for Level 2 attachments.